# How can I use one large image and break it apart into smaller pieces for a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, css-sprites

So I've seen a method that several people seem to use where they have one large image (a master template image, if you will), and after that image is loaded, there is some sort of script or coding that can isolate individual parts of the image and use just that smaller part for an element such as a button. Such is the case with the letter tiles on Words With Friends on Facebook. I'm not talking about how to use Photoshop to separate them. I'm hoping for a web page on the matter as well will hopefully some tutorials or examples. I'm looking for something I can do with HTML, CSS, or JavaScript. Or even jQuery.

Sorry I can't provide any code, since that's what I'm after, and I don't know exactly what this method is called either.

Answer (score 6):

There's a CSS technique called spriting.  I've found the following article explains it brilliantly:

[CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why They’re Cool, and How To Use Them](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)